# How can this line add array with constants?

Tags: arrays, c, emulation

I'm looking at the [line 272](https://github.com/adriancable/8086tiny/blob/c79ca2a34d96931d55ef724c815b289d0767ae3a/8086tiny.c#L272) of the [8086tiny](https://github.com/adriancable/8086tiny)'s source code. There is

```
// regs16 and reg8 point to F000:0, the start of memory-mapped registers. CS is initialised to F000
regs16 = (unsigned short *)(regs8 = mem + REGS_BASE);
```

while `REGS_BASE` is

```
#define RAM_SIZE 0x10FFF0
#define REGS_BASE 0xF0000
```

[Line 158 & 159](https://github.com/adriancable/8086tiny/blob/c79ca2a34d96931d55ef724c815b289d0767ae3a/8086tiny.c#L158) define `mem`, `regs8` and `regs16` as

```
unsigned char mem[RAM_SIZE],*regs8;
unsigned short *regs16;
```

So my question is: What does the line `regs8 = mem + REGS_BASE` do and how can it possible to add an array(`mem`) with a constant(`REGS_BASE`)? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Adding an integer N to an array produces a pointer pointing to the N-th element of that array

Comment: So it equal to `regs8 = mem[REGS_BASE]`?

Comment: no `&mem[REGS_BASE]`

Comment: Ok thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **How can this line add array with constants?**

The C standard says (copied from ISO/IEC 9899:201x Committee Draft — April 12, 2011 N1570):

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the
> unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
> type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points
> to the initial element of the array object ...

So when using an array, i.e. `mem`, in an expression of the form `mem + ...`, `mem` is converted to a **pointer to the first element of the array**.

For addition the standard says:

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the
> result has the type of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of
> an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from
> the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original
> array elements equals the integer expression. In other words, if the expression P points to
> the i-th element of an array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and
> (P)-N (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i+n-th and i−n-th elements of
> the array object, provided they exist.

So adding an integer N to a pointer to an array element will give you a pointer to the element N positions after the element pointed to by the original pointer.

In your case this means:

```
Pointer to first element (aka pointer to mem[0])
 |
 |       Integer
 |        |
/-\   /-------\

mem + REGS_BASE

\-------------/
       |
      Pointer to the REGS_BASE'th element (aka pointer to mem[REGS_BASE])
```

In your code this pointer is assigned both to `reg8` and - after casting - to `reg16`.

Answer (score 1):

Array name represents the first element address.

```
unsigned char mem[RAM_SIZE];
```

`mem` is equal to `&mem[0]`

Becides: (n is constant)
`mem[n] = *(mem + n)`

`mem + n` is an address that you can assign it to an appropriate pointer.

Comment: I prefer to call the `pointer type`  as `address type`(informally), which means that you can assign an address(if you know it or be obtained by the character `&`) to its value, and the address variable store an address that can be used by charachter `*` to access or change another variable.